# How rendering marked date in Calendar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, calendar

I created a calendar in a react-native app and I would like to display a blue circle around the date that I have clicked. But I don't success to display it.

This is my code:

```js
 const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(moment()
     .utcOffset('+01:00')
     .format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
 const [dateLimited, setDateLimited] = useState(moment()
    .utcOffset('+01:00')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

return(
     <Calendar markedDates={{currentDate: {selected: true} }} style={{ width: wp('80%'), height: hp('30%') }} minDate={'2020-01-01'} maxDate={dateLimited} onDayPress={(day)=> setCurrentDate( moment(day.dateString).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}></Calendar>
);
```

What is strange is that when I write the date directly like this it works:

```js
<Calendar markedDates={{'2020-04-28': {selected: true} }} style={{ width: wp('80%'), height: hp('30%') }} minDate={'2020-01-01'} maxDate={dateLimited} 
                onDayPress={(day)=> setCurrentDate( moment(day.dateString).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}></Calendar>
```

And if I display in console.log currentDate, I got the right date :

```js
2020-04-28
```

Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this sample created using class component - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59602003/9432559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the first comment of this SO question:[JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11508463/11251665)

To evaluate `currentDate` instead of just using it as a key, you have to put square brackets around: `markedDates={[currentDate]: {selected: true}}`