# Using react-native-calendars, how to update 'markedDates' prop from redux state?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-calendars

I would like to use react-native-calendars to highlight events with 'markedDates'.

What I am trying to do is the following:

Calender renders first time with current month
--> dispatch redux action to update the redux state with the dates for displayed month
--> in markedDates I use a function to read the dates to be marked from redux state

When changing to the next month the same happen again
--> dispatch redux action to fetch data of the currently displayed month
--> function in markedDates returns updated object

This works for the first render but I can't dynamically update the markedDates prop.

I understand, that markedDates must be immutable and this is actually my issue (I guess - I am still a rookie in react-natvie).

It would be OK to just fully re-render the calendar component - but foreRender() or shoudComponentUpdate() don't help.

Any idea out there how I can make this calender component dynamic?
Or are there any suggestions for another component with calender and agenda views?

Thanks!

Comment: This might helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59602003/9432559

Answer (score 0):

For all reading through that description - here is the answer.

This is not a problem from the react-native-calendars component.

The issue was in my code where I was kind of trying to read the markedDates from the local state rather from the redux-state.

There was some logic required to translate the dates stored in the redux-store in the right format for the react-native-calendars component.

I tried to have a function in my component to do this function got never ever triggered when the component reloaded.

Anyway - I refactored the redux-action to do the conversion for me and stored the markedDates ready to use in the redux-state.

That did the trick and wokrs perfect for me.